# Unable to cast object of type System.Int64 to type System.Int32

Tags: c#, sql

I get `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Int32'` on:

```
item.ItemCount = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("amount"));
```

I tried:

```
item.ItemCount = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("amount"));
```

But I got:

```
Error   CS0266  
Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The field is `bigint` and this is my first experience with .Net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `GetInt64`

```
item.ItemCount = reader.GetInt64(reader.GetOrdinal("amount"));
```

SQL `bigint` is the equivalent to .NET `long`, `GetInt64` returns a `long`, while `GetInt32` returns an `int`.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=netframework-4.8#methods) for more detail.

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You have to modify the `ItemCount` property to be of type long as well.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that

Comment: I think this is the one InventoryInfo item = new InventoryInfo();

Comment: Ok, now can you share the code for the `InventoryInfo` class?

Comment: List<InventoryInfo> inventoryList = new List<InventoryInfo>();

Comment: No, that's just a variable. Where is `InventoryInfo` defined?

Comment: did it  public long ItemCount { get; set; }, thank you so much